# Move rows to different excelfiles matching multiple cellvalues per file

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to move the rows of a large-ish excel file into different excel files. Multiple matching cell values from a single column in the source file will need to be moved to each destination file. I would like to do this in an easily extensible way since there will be an increasing number of cell value and destination file pairs in the future.

In my current implementation I first move the rows to separate sheets, one for each destination file and later make separate files from each sheets, that part of the code works well and for brevity I have not included it in this question.

So far I have tried using the following for moving the rows to their respctive new worksheets, and it  works but has made for lots of redundancies in the code. I have included a code sample using just one pair, "PRE Name1*" which goes in the sheet "Destfile1", in my current project I have the big code block repeated for every pair, which makes the project not very easy to work with. The first part of the pair, that matches the cell value is using wildcard matching since most of the values have common prefixes in their names.

```
Sub SplitOnCellvalues()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    
    I = Worksheets("Source").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Destfile1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Destfile1").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Source").Range("O1:O" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) Like "PRE Name1*" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Destfile1").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            K = K - 1
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I currently also have a separate sub that pre-creates the sheets so it is safe to assume they exist.

I have also tried to build a multidimensional array that I could iterate over instead, but I can't seem to find a good way to build the array that feels like it will scale well when the list of pairs grow larger.

To illustrate the list of matching cell values and destination sheets they need to be moved to looks similar to this

```
"PRE Name1*" "Destfile1111"
"PRE Name2*" "DestfileAAAA"
"PRE AAAAA*" "Destfile1111"
"PRE DDDDD*" "Destfile2222"
"PRE Name4*" "DestfileAAAA"
"PRE Name4*" "DestfileAAAA"
```

I am mostly looking for a way to do this with fairly clean and extensible code as this project will need to be amended with new pairs of cell values and destination files on at least a monthly basis for the foreseeable future.

Comment: So the question isn't so much about moving the data to a different file, but rather splitting it into separate sheets as you have code that works for moving those sheets into different files.
"PRE Name1"  is just the start of the (example) text to be found?  So it could be "PRE Name1ABC" or "PRE NAME12"

Comment: Yes, the end goal is different files, but the solution i have now first moves to different sheets and a separate sub moves to different files in a later stage. You are also correct that the names need wildcard matching, at least in most of the instances.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have tried to edit in my clarifications i the question as well. Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want.  It doesn't delete the source range though.
I haven't added the * wildcard to the end of each value. It gets added during the filter.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitOnCellValues()
   
    Dim MatchesArray() As Variant
    MatchesArray = Array("PRE Name1", "Destfile1111", _
                         "PRE Name2", "DestfileAAAA", _
                         "PRE AAAAABV", "Destfile1111", _
                         "ABC", "Destfile1234")
                         
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    
    'Make sure the source sheet isn't filtered and set a range
    'to the data including and excluding headers.
    With SourceSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
                         
        Dim SourceLastCell As Range
        Set SourceLastCell = LastCell(SourceSheet)
    
        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Set SourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), SourceLastCell)
        
        Dim SourceData As Range
        Set SourceData = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), SourceLastCell)
    End With
                         
    'Loop through the array and filter the source data.
    'If data is found then copy the visible rows to the bottom of the required sheet.
    Dim TargetLastCell As Range
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(MatchesArray) To UBound(MatchesArray) Step 2
        SourceRange.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=MatchesArray(x) & "*"
    
        If SourceRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MatchesArray(x + 1))
            Set TargetLastCell = LastCell(TargetSheet)
            
            SourceData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                Destination:=TargetSheet.Cells(TargetLastCell.Row + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next x
                         
End Sub

'Find the last cell on a sheet.  Returns A1 if the sheet is empty.
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With wrkSht
        LastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With
    
    If LastCol = 0 Then LastCol = 1
    If LastRow = 0 Then LastRow = 1
    
    Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)
    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```